# Can't boot or see Windows 7 particition after installing Ubuntu

Tags: installation, windows, boot-repair

I installed Ubuntu earlier today and I can't see Windows 7 partition in Gparted and don't get an option to boot Windows 7 at restart.

When I was installing Ubuntu, I chose "Something else" option and partitioned about 100 GBs of "Unallocated space". It did not show Windows 7 in those partitions at that time or right now.

After googling and trying different things I still was not be able to fix anything.

I tried running Boot Repair after booting from Live USB, but that did not help.

This is the Boot Repair log file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6349990/

Can anyone please suggest what to do to recover Windows 7 or at least the files? Please help! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You have erased Windows by installing Ubuntu above it. To recover your lost files, you can try using TestDisk: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step